# Cannot connect to internet (Windows XP)

Tags: networking, windows-xp, wireless-networking

Trying to save an Acer Aspire One, with Windows XP (32-bit Home).

The computer stopped connecting to the internet (wireless or cable) after removing an old version of Avast.

Have tried system restore points, but these fail for some reason; have reinstalled drivers; have run a special Avast cleaner in Safe mode (which did remove a few more traces of Avast); have turned off Windows Firewall.

Nothing helps.

The hardware is fine, because I can boot xubuntu on a USB stick and internet connections are fine.

Is there anything else that I can try?

Here is the ipconfig report

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\Acer>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

        Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Julia
        Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
        Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcast
        IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
        WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

        Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR5007EG Wireless Network Adapter
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-22-69-87-2B-ED

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 9:

        Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8102E Family PCI-E Fast E
thernet NIC
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1E-68-D2-C0-7D
```

Comment: Realize that it's beyond foolish to connect a WinXP machine to the internet past the end of support, and just install a *nix of choice... I do have a WinXP machine I still run for a particular program. It hasn't met the internet in years.

Answer (score 0):

[This Realtek Drivers Page](http://www.realtek.com.tw/Downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=7&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3) shows that Realtek released an updated driver for the RTL8102E earlier this year.  If you only reinstalled the included driver, there might be a fix in this more recent driver.

Comment: Worth a try, but sadly it didn't help. Both wireless and wired connectivity is affected, so it is a bit optimistic expect one new driver to make a difference. My guess is that Avast somehow redirected all internet communication and that the removal of the antivirus did not restore the original configuration. I did try reinstalling Avast, but I didn't have the original version and so I wasn't able to really restore the earlier setup.